# Looping assets and entries together

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, contentful

I have managed to loop out all content from a specific ContentType and everything works well except that the entries are not followed by their specific assets.

In this specific case it renders as:
Entry 1
Entry 2
Entry 3
Asset 1
Asset 2
Asset 3

I want it to render as: Entry 1 Asset 1, Entry 2 Asset 2 etc...

Putting the asset array loop inside the fields loop didn't help :)

Javascript

```
client.getEntries({
    include: 1,
    'content_type': 'posts'
})
.then((response) => {

    var template = $('#myEntries').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response.toPlainObject());
    $('.result').html(html);

})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error occured')
    console.log(error)
})
```

HTML

```
<script id="myEntries" type="text/template">
    {{#items}}
        <h1>{{fields.header}}</h1>
        <p>{{fields.description}}</p>
    {{/items}}

    {{#includes.Asset}}
        <p>File: <img src="https:{{fields.file.url}}?fit=thumb&f=top_left&h=200&w=200" width="100"/></p>
    {{/includes.Asset}}
</script>

<div class="result"></div>
```

JSON
https://jsfiddle.net/pcgn73zf/

Would love your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi maybe you missed it in the docs but the contentful js SDK already does link resolution, for example, if you have a contentType post that has an image field, when you get an entry you can access directly the fields of the asset. so to get the `url` from the linked asset you just request `myEntry.fields.image.fields.file.url`. No need to request it form includes.
the asset part in your code should be (assuming that the asset field is called image)

```
 <p>File: <img src="https:{{fields.image.fields.file.url}}?fit=thumb&f=top_left&h=200&w=200" width="100"/></p>
```

Please note that link resolution only works when requesting the collection endpoint `client.getEntries()`
for more infos check this README [section](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js#link-resolution)

Comment: I have read about link resolution but didn't get it purpose! Thanks again mate. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are flattering JSON with `response.toPlainObject()`. Try reading required properties in desired order.

Example:

```js
var input = {
  entries: [
    {
      text: "Entry 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Entry 2"
    }
  ],
  assets: [
    {
      text: "Asset 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Asset 2"
    }
  ]
};

var i = 0;
while (i < Math.max(input.entries.length, input.assets.length)) {
  if (i < input.entries.length) {
    document.write(input.entries[i].text + ", ");
  }
  if (i < input.assets.length) {
    document.write(input.assets[i].text + ", ");
  }
  i++;
}
```